# A computation with derivations and skew-derivations

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

On a smooth manifold $M$ a *derivation* $D$ of degree $k$ is an endomorphism of the algebra of forms defined on $M$, which is denoted by $\Omega(M) = \bigoplus_{k \geq 0} \Omega^k(M)$, such that

1. $D\colon \Omega^r(M) \to \Omega^{r+k}(M)$ for all $r$.
2. $D$ satisfies $D(\alpha \wedge \beta) = D\alpha \wedge \beta + \alpha \wedge D\beta.$

It is called *skew-derivation* if 2. is replaced by $D(\alpha \wedge \beta) = D\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^{l}\alpha \wedge D\beta$, where $l$ is the degree of $\alpha$, and means that $\alpha \in \Omega^l(M)$.

> Prove that if $D$ is a derivation of degree $k$ and $D'$ is a skew-derivation of degree $k'$, then $[D,D']:= DD'-D'D$ is a skew-derivation of degree $k+k'$.

I cannot see where my computations go wrong:

\begin{align}
[D,D'](\alpha \wedge \beta) & = DD'(\alpha \wedge \beta) - D'D(\alpha \wedge \beta) \\
& = D(D'\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^{\deg \alpha}\alpha \wedge D'\beta)-D'(D\alpha \wedge \beta + \alpha \wedge D\beta) \\
& = DD'\alpha \wedge \beta + D'\alpha \wedge D\beta + (-1)^{\deg \alpha}D\alpha \wedge D'\beta + (-1)^{\deg \alpha}\alpha \wedge DD'\beta \\
& \quad -D'D\alpha \wedge \beta - (-1)^{\deg \alpha+k}D\alpha \wedge D'\beta-D'\alpha \wedge D\beta-(-1)^{\deg \alpha}\alpha \wedge D'D\beta \\
& = [D,D']\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^{\deg \alpha}\alpha \wedge [D,D']\beta+(-1)^{\deg \alpha}(1-(-1)^k)D\alpha \wedge D'\beta.
\end{align}

So the statement seems to hold only when $k$ is even. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\alpha, \beta$ are differential forms and let $D$ be a derivation of order $k$. We have two relevant cases:

1. $\alpha$ of even degree and $\beta$ of odd degree.
2. Both $\alpha,\beta$ of odd degree.

In the first case we have
\begin{align}
D(\alpha \wedge \beta) & = D\alpha \wedge \beta + \alpha \wedge D\beta,\\
D(\beta \wedge \alpha) & = D\beta \wedge \alpha + \beta \wedge D\alpha = \alpha \wedge D\beta +(-1)^kD\alpha \wedge \beta.
\end{align}
First and second line must now agree, which implies that either $k$ is even or $D$ (of odd order) vanishes on even degree forms.

Second case:
\begin{align}
D(\alpha \wedge \beta) & = D\alpha \wedge \beta + \alpha \wedge D\beta,\\
-D(\beta \wedge \alpha) & = -D\beta \wedge \alpha - \beta \wedge D\alpha = (-1)^k(\alpha \wedge D\beta +D\alpha \wedge \beta).
\end{align}
Again, the two lines agree. Now, either $k$ is even, or it is odd and then $D$ vanishes on odd degree forms.

Summing up, either $k$ is even, or $D$ vanishes. This should prove that derivations of odd order vanish and that non-trivial derivations have even order.

Thus, there is no loss of generality in assuming $k$ even. In this case the term giving problems vanishes and the statement holds true.

Comment: This doesn't look correct. For example, when $M$ is one-dimensional, the exterior derivative is both a derivation of degree one and a skew-derivation of degree one which is not trivial...

Comment: @levap You are right, I agree. Thanks for giving your feedback, I spent a big part of the afternoon on this problem and ended up with a wrong answer. Good... Then I do not see how the statement I posted could be correct. It was taken by "Kobayashi and Nomizu - Foundations of Differential Geometry", vol. 1. Do you know how to prove it?